# How do I wait for a Firebase function to complete before continuing my code flow in SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, firebase, function, swiftui

I have a Firebase function in a class (listenToUser) that works fine but I noticed that the next code (the IF ELSE) does not wait for it to complete before continuing. How can I wait for my function to be completed before continuing my code?

Portion of code of my main view :

```
...

@EnvironmentObject var firebaseSession: FirebaseSession_VM

...
        .onAppear {
            firebaseSession.listenToUser()
            
                if firebaseSession.firebaseUser == nil {
                    showSignInView = true
                } else {
                    showSignInStep1View = true
                }
   }
```

My function :

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import FirebaseAuth

class FirebaseSession_VM: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = FirebaseSession_VM()
    
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<FirebaseSession_VM, Never>()
    
    @Published var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser_M? {
        didSet {
            self.didChange.send(self)
        }
    }
    
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listenToUser () {
        // monitor authentication changes using firebase
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                self.firebaseUser = FirebaseUser_M(
                    id: user.uid,
                    email: user.email
                )
            } else {
                self.firebaseUser = nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: U should not wait because it blocks UI, which is bad, instead use some placeholders/progress_labels for the UI elements which will be updated once real data received.

Comment: You are using `ObservableObject` **and** a Combine subject, which are perfect candidates to get notified rather than waiting for something.

Comment: Asperi, i have to wait or something else because the user is always NIL in the IF ELSE because it takes sometime to get the result from Firebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of Firebase's API calls are asynchronous, which is why you need to either register a state listener or use callbacks.

Two side notes:

1. You should not implement `ObservableObjects` as singletons. Use `@StateObject` instead, to make sure SwiftUI can properly manage its state.
2. You no longer need to use `PassthroughSubject` directly. It's easier to use the `@Published` property wrapper instead.

That being said, here are a couple of code snippets that show how you can implement Email/Password Authentication with SwiftUI:

## Main View

The main view shows if you're sign in. If you're not signed in, it will display a button that will open a separate sign in screen.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(" Hello!")
        .font(.title3)
      
      switch viewModel.isSignedIn {
      case true:
        VStack {
          Text("You're signed in.")
          Button("Tap here to sign out") {
            viewModel.signOut()
          }
        }
      default:
        VStack {
          Text("It looks like you're not signed in.")
          Button("Tap here to sign in") {
            viewModel.signIn()
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $viewModel.isShowingLogInView) {
      SignInView()
    }
  }
}
```

The main view's view model listens for any auth state changes and updates the `isSignedIn` property accordingly. This drives the `ContentView` and what it displays.

```swift
import Foundation
import Firebase

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var isSignedIn = false
  @Published var isShowingLogInView = false
  
  init() {
    // listen for auth state change and set isSignedIn property accordingly
    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
      if let user = user {
        print("Signed in as user \(user.uid).")
        self.isSignedIn = true
      }
      else {
        self.isSignedIn = false
      }
    }
  }
  
  /// Show the sign in screen
  func signIn() {
    isShowingLogInView = true
  }
  
  /// Sign the user out
  func signOut() {
    do {
      try Auth.auth().signOut()
    }
    catch {
      print("Error while trying to sign out: \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

## SignIn View

The `SignInView` shows a simple email/password form with a button. The interesting thing to note here is that it listens for any changes to the `viewModel.isSignedIn` property, and calls the `dismiss` action (which it pulls from the environment). Another option would be to implement a callback as a trailing closure on the view model's `signIn()` method.

```swift
struct SignInView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @StateObject var viewModel = SignInViewModel()
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Hi!")
        .font(.largeTitle)
      Text("Please sign in.")
        .font(.title3)
      Group {
        TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
          .disableAutocorrection(true)
          .autocapitalization(.none)
        SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
      }
      .padding()
      .background(Color(UIColor.systemFill))
      .cornerRadius(8.0)
      .padding(.bottom, 8)
      
      Button("Sign in") {
        viewModel.signIn()
      }
      .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
      .padding(.vertical, 16)
      .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
      .background(Color.accentColor)
      .cornerRadius(8)
    }
    .padding()
    .onChange(of: viewModel.isSignedIn) { signedIn in
      dismiss()
    }
  }
}
```

The `SignInViewModel` has a method `signIn` that performs the actual sign in process by calling `Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail:password:)`. As you can see, it will change the view model's `isSignedIn` property to `true` if the user was authenticated.

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var password: String = ""
  
  @Published var isSignedIn: Bool = false
  
  func signIn() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authDataResult, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("There was an issue when trying to sign in: \(error)")
        return
      }
      
      guard let user = authDataResult?.user else {
        print("No user")
        return
      }
      
      print("Signed in as user \(user.uid), with email: \(user.email ?? "")")
      self.isSignedIn = true
    }
  }
}
```

## Alternative: Using Combine

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseAuthCombineSwift

class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var password: String = ""
  
  @Published var isSignedIn: Bool = false

  // ...

  func signIn() {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
      .map { $0.user }
      .replaceError(with: nil)
      .print("User signed in")
      .map { $0 != nil }
      .assign(to: &$isSignedIn)
  }
}
```

## Alternative: Using async/await

```swift
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

class SignInViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var email: String = ""
  @Published var password: String = ""
  
  @Published var isSignedIn: Bool = false
  

  @MainActor
  func signIn() async {
    do {
      let authDataResult = try 3 await 1 Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
      let user = authDataResult.user
    
      print("Signed in as user \(user.uid), with email: \(user.email ?? "")")
      self.isSignedIn = true
    }
    catch {
      print("There was an issue when trying to sign in: \(error)")
      self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
    }
  }
}
```

## More details

I wrote an article about this in which I explain the individual techniques in more detail: [Calling asynchronous Firebase APIs from Swift - Callbacks, Combine, and async/await](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firebase-async-calls-swift/). If you'd rather watch a video, I've got you covered as well: [3 easy tips for calling async APIs](https://youtu.be/j5htIyxmmzA?t=224s)

Comment: Hi @Peter Friese, yes im interested for the async/await method, thanks.

Comment: I wrote an entire article about this: [Calling asynchronous Firebase APIs from Swift - Callbacks, Combine, and async/await](https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firebase-async-calls-swift/), and also recorded a video (coming soon).

Comment: Thank you so much!